# Strassen matrixes multiplication source code

Tags: c#, c++

I need to Strassen source code.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to Strassen your source code, you should first check if doing that is legal in your jurisdiction.

Then you need to verify whether you need to be a licensed practitioner to do so. If a license is required and you are not one, you need to find a licensing practitioner - I would recommend Yellow Pages or Google.

You also need to pay attention to your local ethical/morality standards. In certain communities you might get shunned or frowned upon if you Strassen your source code.

Comment: thanks alot.can i have u're yahoo id?

Answer (score 1):

Source code for C (easily adaptable to C++, C#) available at:

http://gitorious.org/intelws2010/matrix-multiplication/blobs/master/src/matmul.c

which was linked to from Wikipedia, the first hit on search results.  Really, what work did you do to find this?

Comment: "Really, what work did you do to find this?" - He posted on SO, you found it.